# Is it possible that exactly one of $G$ and $H$ has an Euler trail, if both graphs are homeomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, eulerian-path

> Let $G$ and $H$ be loop-free homeomorphic undirected graphs with no
>   isolated vertices. Is it possible that exactly one of $G$ and $H$ has
>   an Euler trail?

My approach is that if graph $G$ has an Euler trail then all of its homeomorphic graphs have Euler trail because each subdivison of $G$ creates a vertex with even degree; so it does not break property of Euler trailer as there will always be two vertices with odd degree.

Answer (score 1):

To mark this question answered: you are right.

Comment: So the way to prove would be to say that if G has Euler trail then all of its homeomorphic graphs have Euler trail. And if G does not have Euler trail then all of its homeomorphic graphs do not have Euler trail. Would this be sufficient?

Comment: @PhoxKiD Yes, since subdivisions do not change the number of vertices of odd degree, $G$ has an Eulerian traill iff each its subdivision has an Eulerian traill iff some its subdivision has an Eulerian traill. This is true both for open and for closed trails.